# Xamarin.Android : trying to Install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat package

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-appcompat

I am trying to install Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat into my application but it wont successfully install and I am getting the following error :
Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.1'.

You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your current project is targeting `Android 6.0` but `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat 25.1.1` that you are trying to install requires your project to target at least Android 7.0.

So you can fix the problem by:

If you are using Visual Studio, right click your project-> properties->Application Manifest->Modify `Target Android Version` to Android 7.0 or higher.

Alternatively, you can fix the problem by changing the version of `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat` to 24.x.x.

Comment: In my project properties, it shows latest version as android marshmallow and i have a phone with android marshmallow which i am using for live preview. What should i change to target marshmallow

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question, could you please explain it in details?

Answer (score 2):

target version 7.1

**Android 7** (api 24) mean your support library should be **24**

**Android 7.1** (api 25 ) mean your support library should be **25**

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while downloading **Xamarin.Android.Support.Design** library which is parent for lot more other libraries.
Even after following the accepted answer I was getting same error followed by other random errors.

I successfully resolved It by following under mentioned steps

VS-2017

-> tools

-> options

-> locate nuget package manager

-> clear All nuget Caches

-> close VS

-> delete packages folder from you project directory

-> delete .vs,bin and obj folder from project

-> restart VS

-> try updating/installing package to the latest api that is available in sdk manager

Comment: tks! this solution worked fine when I transfer a Xamarin project on TFS to another computer. (Got several erros about "Android.Support" package)